# infinite loop when entering data in onStop

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager

In the project I have 1 mainActivity and 4 fragments.
Fragmentes are opened with ViewPager as bottomNavbar.
I use FireBase in the project. And when I first log in, I list the data with fragmentte recyclerview which opens on mainActivity.
But when you exit the application with mAuth.SignOut, the login screen comes up. After inputting on this screen, the onStop method enters the endless loop. The application will continuously open the fragment and return to mainActivity.

When I try with onStop Toast, it prints on the first boot. There is no problem if there is no code to add firebase data in onStop. But I need to add onStop to do an "online" check.

```
12-14 21:08:07.237 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/LoginActivity: Login 

12-14 21:08:07.267 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity paused, time: 24612278

12-14 21:08:07.307 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-14 21:08:07.327 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Using measurement service
12-14 21:08:07.327 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-14 21:08:07.337 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: ActivityMAin onCreate 
12-14 21:08:07.337 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: ActivityMAin mDatabaseUser 
12-14 21:08:07.357 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: ActivityMain SetupViewPager
12-14 21:08:07.357 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: ActivityMAin onStart 

12-14 21:08:07.357 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 24612375

12-14 21:08:07.717 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/android:switcher:2131231057:0: onCreate Main FRAGMENT
-
12-14 21:08:07.847 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity paused, time: 24612872
-
12-14 21:08:07.927 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-14 21:08:07.957 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main onCreate oldu
12-14 21:08:07.957 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main mDatabaseUser oldu
12-14 21:08:07.957 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Burası Main SetupViewPager
12-14 21:08:07.957 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main onStart oldu
12-14 21:08:07.957 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 24612979


12-14 21:08:07.987 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/android:switcher:2131231057:0: onCreate Main FRAGMENT

12-14 21:08:08.287 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.287 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.307 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.307 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent

12-14 21:08:08.507 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.507 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.517 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.517 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.517 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.597 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.647 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.647 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:08.657 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:08.657 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.657 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.657 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:08.657 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:08.667 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.667 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.667 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7278bbf time:18352916
12-14 21:08:08.677 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: ---------------------------OnStop----------------------------
12-14 21:08:08.677 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-14 21:08:08.677 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.hasan.simpleblog time:18352927
12-14 21:08:08.727 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 771
12-14 21:08:08.727 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity paused, time: 24613750
12-14 21:08:08.747 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main onCreate oldu
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main mDatabaseUser oldu
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Burası Main SetupViewPager
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main onStart oldu
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 24613808
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{bd3b772 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-14 21:08:08.787 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-14 21:08:08.797 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/android:switcher:2131231057:0: onCreate Main FRAGMENT
12-14 21:08:08.847 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.847 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.857 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
12-14 21:08:08.887 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
12-14 21:08:08.927 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.927 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.937 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.937 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:08.937 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.987 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:08.997 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.hasan.simpleblog time:18353247
12-14 21:08:09.027 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 245
12-14 21:08:09.027 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity paused, time: 24614052
12-14 21:08:09.047 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-14 21:08:09.087 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main onCreate oldu
12-14 21:08:09.087 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main mDatabaseUser oldu
12-14 21:08:09.087 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Burası Main SetupViewPager
12-14 21:08:09.087 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/com.example.hasan.simpleblog: Main onStart oldu
12-14 21:08:09.087 2004-2117/com.example.hasan.simpleblog V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 24614111
12-14 21:08:09.087 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
12-14 21:08:09.097 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{689b9c7 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-14 21:08:09.107 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/android:switcher:2131231057:0: onCreate Main FRAGMENT
12-14 21:08:09.147 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.147 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.147 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
12-14 21:08:09.167 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
12-14 21:08:09.167 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:09.187 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:09.187 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:09.197 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:09.197 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
12-14 21:08:09.197 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.217 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.277 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.277 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:09.277 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: In onDataChange
12-14 21:08:09.287 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.287 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-14 21:08:09.287 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1269f06 time:18353538
12-14 21:08:09.287 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: ---------------------------OnStop----------------------------
12-14 21:08:09.297 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
12-14 21:08:09.307 2004-2004/com.example.hasan.simpleblog I/System.out: ---------------------------OnStop----------------------------


 @Override
public void onStop() {

        mDatabaseUsers.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Do you have an active Firebase database listener on the location you are writing to? If so, its `onDataChange()` will fire and perhaps cause the looping you are observing.

Comment: @BobSnyder I am using onDataChange in onStart. I will put it in front of it.

Comment: How to how to ?